# Why can't a thread-unsafe class work while using just getter and setter?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a class as follow:

```
public class BoolFlag
{
boolean flag;

public BoolFlag()
{
    flag=false;
}

public synchronized void setFlag(boolean flag)
{
    this.flag=flag;
}

public synchronized boolean getFlag()
{
    return flag;
}
}
```

If I don't set the getter and setter to be synchronized,it would cause the problem as follow:

When I set an object of BoolFlag called imageready in one buttonclick listiner:

```
 if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
           { 
               try
               {
                    System.out.println("File chosen");
                    imgFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();  
                    image.setImg( ImageIO.read(imgFile) );
                    imageready.setFlag(true);

               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   System.out.println("file not opened");
                }
            }
```

Then get it in another thread:

```
public void run()
{
    boolean running=true;
    while(running)
    {
        // System.out.println("Img sender running");
        if(imageready.getFlag())
        { System.out.println("trying to send img");
            try
            {
                  OutputStream outputStream = img_s.getOutputStream();
                  ImageIO.write(image.getImg(), "jpg", outputStream);

                  System.out.println("Send image"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                  outputStream.flush();
                  outputStream.close();
                  imageready.setFlag(false);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("image client send failed");
                imageready.setFlag(false);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

What I expect is after choosing the file, the imageready should be set to true, then the thread who get the flag execute the statements inside the block:

```
if(imageready.getFlag()){...send image...}
```

But it won't goes into the block even though the imageready is set to be true.

As you might notice, I have a statement being commented out right before the if block:

```
// System.out.println("Img sender running");
```

If I don't comment it out, the statements in the if block would be executed. Putting other unrelated statements like sleep(100) could result in the same effect. If I put a break point at the if(imageready.getflag()), and then execute it step by step,it would also goes into the block.

If I set the getter and setter to be synchronized, these problem won't happen.
Seems that it's something about the Tread-safe class but I can't figure out  why it matter even though I just use the getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

Your get accessor is likely being inlined such that it is effectively just a field read, and the runtime may optimize away simple field reads which appear in a loop such that the value is effectively read only once.

You can avoid this by reading a `volatile` value or, as you noticed, by using `synchronized` to force a memory barrier when the flag is written and read.

In your case, I would simply use an `AtomicBoolean` in place of your `BoolFlag` class.

On a side note, I would avoid busy-spinning on your "image ready" flag on the second thread.  Consider using a wait notification mechanism, e.g., a `CountDownLatch` with a count of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is due to thread communication, and what you are trying to achieve is [Product-Consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Few issues with your code:

1) The thread class which writes the image file, is not blocked inside `getFlag()` method, so your while loop might be running a lot keeping the thread active. Instead block the thread inside `getFlag()` and make use of `wait()` and `notifyAll()` methods for effective thread communication.

[Java example of producer-consumer problem](http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/12/producer-consumer-problem-with-wait-and-notify-example.html). You need to do similar thing to manage threads in your case.

Comment: In the producer-consumer problem, producer and consumer would modify the same object. But my situation is a little bit different： one thread is modifying the value of imageready while the other one just get it without changing its value.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization provides no of facility to write a thread safe class. In a multithreaded environment if an object is shared amongs threads, There are no of issue which may impact the correctness of your program like, data race, dirty reads, stale value.

To optimize your code java save variable data in memory buffer for faster access. Due to that changes made by other thread to that variable may not reflect instantly that's why other thread read the previous value of the variable hence not being able to read the updated value in near future.

You can define your variable as volatile. Volatile make sure that thread will get the recently updated value for the variable as committed by Java Memory Model.

Comment: But the if(imageready.getFlag()) would be kept running and  keep checking if the imageready is changed to true since it is in the while(true) loop in a thread. So why it wouldn't get the updated value for the imageready? Thanks.

Comment: As I said each thread have it's own stack area and value stored in register so once it is catched ...it may not be able to get the updated value....